# Prevent user to go to the new action if the record exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I have the following problem with my rails application:

I have two models, User and Information, the user, create his information using this url:

> users/id/information/new

and edit his information using this url:

> users/id/information/id/edit

The problem if the following, after the user create his information, if he go to the url:

> users/id/information/new

the record is deleted from the data base and the user it's allowed to create a new record; this is totally wrong, because the user is only allow to create one user information and then he can only edit his record.

How can I denied the user to go to new action url if the user have a record on the information table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a before filter to the action new, then, inside that filter check if the user information exists

```
UserInformationsController
  before_filter :require_no_user_information, :only => :new

  def require_no_user_information
    if UserInformation.exists?(:user_id => params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = 'The user information already exists'
      redirect_to edit_user_information_path params[:id]
      false
    end
  end
end
```

the filter will redirect and return false with a flash message if the user information exists, the code is an example, I don't know your models